# Crystal reports crosstabs column grouping

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I'm trying to build a cross tab report in Crystal XI that has dates, grouped by the month as column heading, and have 2 questions I'm trying to find answers to.

1: Is there any way to display a month even if there are no records to be summarized in that month? i.e. no orders for March, but want to display Jan, Feb, Mar.? I'm pretty sure I can create a dates table and use that spoof it, but don't want to go that route as the database is part of a Vendor's package and I don't want to get to crazy in there.

2: Is there a way of specifying or limiting how many columns go across? For example in a forecast cross tab I only owant current month and the next six months to show up. I suppose I can do a date range on the selection criteria, but that seems a bit kludgy to me.

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Short answer: No.
   I've seen discussions about workarounds involving creation of temporary tables, but I've never tried any such solutions myself.
2. I would go with the date range on the selection criteria. You could make those dates parameters for more convenient useage. If you have sevral cross-tabs that should have different date ranges you could put the crosstabs in sub-reports.